# How to give Handler or on click event in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using box component and want to give handler to anchor tag. Can anyone suggest me to get that. In doc not getting handler for box component

My code ;

```
{   
      xtype: 'box',
      autoEl: {tag: 'a', href: '#', children: [{tag: 'div', html: 'Value'}]},
    },
```

I want onclick either on box or `a` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, the box component does not have a `click` event, so you need to place the listener on the element, like so:

```
xtype: 'box',
autoEl: {tag: 'a', href: '#', children: [{tag: 'div', html: 'Value'}]},
listeners: {
    element: 'el',
    click: function() {
        alert('click');
    }
}
```

From the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-listeners):

> While some Ext JS Component classes export selected DOM events (e.g.
>   "click", "mouseover" etc), this is usually only done when extra value
>   can be added. For example the Ext.view.View's itemclick event passing
>   the node clicked on. To access DOM events directly from a child
>   element of a Component, we need to specify the element option to
>   identify the Component property to add a DOM listener to.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/279k